# Audio calling from asterisk to google hangouts

Tags: voip, asterisk, google-hangouts

I can make inbound and outbound calls from asterisk to old gtalk. But I don't know how to make it possible through google hangout.
Is there anybody know how to do this.

In reference to this link.
https://plus.google.com/+NikhylSinghal/posts/DG6h32BWaQW
When I am trying calls from asterisk to make inbound calls in hangout. It says "no gtalk capable clients to talk".

Any help or guidance appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

I think old gtalk used XMPP so Asterisk have module to communication with this.
Google hangout use closed protocol for voice/video call, Asterisk can NOT get communication with Google Hangout so far.